# Finding the overall distance.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I have a problem that's outlined as "The first hour motorcyclist covers 35% of the distance, second hour he covers 0.4, and the third hour he cover 37.5km."

What is the overall distance the motorcyclist cover across three hours.

So $37.5km$ accounts for $60\%$ of the distance. I effectively need to find $100\%$ of the distance.

So to do that I can just do $(37.5 * 0.4)+37.5km = ‭52.5‬$ however, this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hour he covers 35% of the distance, the second hour he covers 0.4=40% of the distance. Therefore in the first 2 hours he covers 75% of the distance. Thus, 100%-75%=25% of the distance is 37.5, and 37.5/(25/100)=37.5*=4=150. Therefore, the total distance is 150 kilometres.